# How can I connect to a wireless network with hidden SSID using the terminal?

Tags: command-line, security, wifi

I'm starting to learn about wireless pentesting with BackTrack, and while learning how to find out the hidden SSID I wondered how could I connect to the wireless network after I discover the SSID. The book I'm studying does not cover that topic, only how to find the SSID.

I tried:

```
ifconfig wlan0 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

```
iwconfig wlan0 essid "XXXX" channel X
```

but that doesn't work. Result in screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Define "that doesn't work". (Are you sure this is an open access point with no WPA2 or WEP?) Also, in the future, please use copy&paste rather than a screenshot.

Comment: @Celada when I try to use the browser it behaves in the same way as a browser with no connection. I'm sure there is no WPA2 or WEP, and I don't know if it is the same thing as closed access, but I'm using the closed network option to hide the SSID. I used the screenshot because I'm doing this on another computer.

Comment: @IvanLerner you don't have any nameserver setup, default routes or anything else. You just connected at the physical layer but you don't have your IP settings configured correctly.

Comment: @UlrichDangel can you give some references or tell me how to do that if it is not a big deal? But I'd like something that really explains it, and not just a walkthrough on how to set it up.

Comment: I don't understand why you closed the question. It is just a question on how to connect to a network without any encryption at all using a hidden SSID. How can that be too specific?

Comment: @IvanLerner: As somebody already noted, the topic of your question actually went just fine ... there is no problem here. "That didn't work" is undefined by your question, but it sounds like you haven't set up the rest of your networking settings (like an IP address). You haven't said enough about your system to get help with those and there is nothing broken here that anybody else could benefit from a solution.